# How to bind() to this mousewheel event that comes in directive form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

There this mousewheel directive that I want to use: https://github.com/monospaced/angular-mousewheel

Its docs tells to either attach it to the element as an attribute or a class,

but I want to attach it to it in my own directive.

```
var myDirective = function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, elem) {
            elem.bind('>>here<<', function(){});
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that directive can't be used in the way you want. However, looking in the [angular-mousewheel source](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-mousewheel/blob/master/mousewheel.js), if you include [Hamster.js](https://github.com/monospaced/hamster.js), as it does, you can do something like:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  var hamster = $window.Hamster(element[0]);
  hamster.wheel(function(e, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    // React to wheel event here
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the directive to your own directive's template:

```
.directive('mwTemplate', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.scroll = function($event, delta, deltax, deltay) {
        console.log($event, delta, deltax, deltay);
      }
    },
    template: '<div msd-wheel="scroll($event, delta, deltax, deltay)">Scroll over top of me</div>'
  };
})
```

... or add it inside of your directive's compile function:

```
.directive('mwCompile', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    scope: {},
    compile: function(elem){
      elem.find('div').attr('msd-wheel', 'scroll($event, delta, deltax, deltay)');
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.scroll = function($event, delta, deltax, deltay) {
        console.log($event, delta, deltax, deltay);
      }
    },
    template: '<div>Scroll over top of me</div>' 
  };
})
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/24wmdOyK7Y4fctMiDlcn?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but it can help someone reading this :

```
element[0].addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', _onWheel, false ); // For FF and Opera
element[0].addEventListener('mousewheel', _onWheel, false ); // For others

function _onWhell(e) {
    // Do what you want here
}
```

We need to use `element[0]` because your original DOM element is wrapped into an another object.